# jQuery toggleClass method not working as expected

Tags: jquery

My code is working as expected if I change from:

```
$('#ftch-master').toggleClass("ftch-nobg");
```

to

```
$('#ftch-master').addClass("ftch-nobg");
```

which means all the elements are referenced correctly and are read by the jquery class library as expected. Successful results are appearing if i run following line of code in the console of the browser

```
$('#ftch-master').toggleClass("ftch-nobg");
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong? Please guide accordingly. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".mobile-position").click(function () {
        $('#ftch-master').toggleClass("ftch-nobg");
    });
});
```

```css
.ftch-main {
  background-image: url(/Content/Images/ftchbg.jpg);
}

.ftch-nobg {
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-position">
</div>
<div id="ftch-master" class="row ftch-main">
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `.mobile-position`? Please revise the snippet above to show the problem, and simplify the question to not include variations of your code. We just need what you're actually using.

Comment: where is button?

Comment: `.mobile-position` is a div. I've added the snippet. Thing is, `.mobile-position` is referenced correctly since `.addClass` method is working just fine.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the click and toggle code inside `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @callback Yes but no avail. I've edited the snippet above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you just add important to the **.ftch-nobg** class so you can override the background, (i would recommend to use only one class for switching the image),
i added some additional styles to demonstrate

```js
$(".mobile-position").click(function() {
  $('#ftch-master').toggleClass("ftch-nobg");
});
```

```css
.ftch-main {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* height: 100%; */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.ftch-nobg {
  background-image: none !important;
  /* no need for the height here */
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile-position" style="width: 40px; height:40px; background-color: red;">
</div>
<div id="ftch-master" class="row ftch-main">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="demo-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and helping. Your code is working fine. Same code is unfortunately not working for me. I've uploaded my recorded screen video to demonstrate my code to you which to me looks 100% same as yours. Here it is for your review. Maybe you could see something that I am not. https://screenrec.com/share/0QW8dbVMTm

Comment: As you can see in the video, clicking `.mobile-position` in my code is not toggling `ftch-nobg` class like it is doing in your code, although our codes are 100% similar.